# How Do You Use Underscore to Sort the Following Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, underscore.js

I want to use underscore to filter **array** by **array1** and get the **answer** below. To be clear, if any of the elements in key1 of the objects in **array** are part of the sentences in **array1** then I want to keep that element in **array**.  For example:

```
var array = [{key: "don't matter", key1: ["Bob doesn't", "Joe lives", "named John"]}, 
{key: "still don't matter", key1: ["Jane might", "Jill lives", "Jennifer can't"]}]

var array1 = ["Someone named Bob lives here", "Someone named Joe lives
 here", "Someone named Lisa lives here"];

var answer = [{key: "don't matter", key1: ["Bob doesn't", "Joe lives", "named John"]}];
```

Right now I'm going down this line:

```
var answerTest = _.filter(array, function(n){if(_.intersection(n.key1, array1))}); //this is not working though

var answerTest2 = _.filter(array, function(n){return RegExp(n.key1).test(????)})
```

I think answerTest2 is a better approach but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Do you mean sort, or filter?

Comment: @torazaburo, I was thinking filter. i want the answer, which has choice elements in array that have specific overlap with elements in array1.  Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var answer = _.filter(array, function(n){
     if (_.some(n.key1, function(j){
        return _.find(array1, function(p){
            return new RegExp(j).test(p)})})) {
              return n}});
```

The purpose of this question was to be able to filter an array of objects by the string value of one of the object's keys and it's partial match with an element in an array of strings.  From what I understand it can't be done without RegExp.  I think this is an important point for people new to Javascript to understand, especially for someone that may be off the normal path performing server side Javascript with underscore or lodash.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11501503)